# How to record video with AR effects and save it?

Tags: android, flutter, arcore

I am trying to create an application like Snapchat that applies face filters while recording the video and saves it with the filter on.
I know there are packages like AR core and flutter_camera_ml_vision but these are not helping me.

I want to provide face filters and apply them at the time of video recording on the face, and also save the video with the filter on the face.

Comment: Not a one-click solution in any way, but I've tried to give an outline of the process in my answer. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I spent a bit of time writing an answer... Would be great if you would confirm that you at least actually read it, even better, add a comment telling me what you think was good (if any) or if something is missing. There are no ways to give an exact answer to your question, so I at least gave it a shot, pointing you in a direction that seemed like the appropriate thing to do...

Comment: fair comment cseder. i agree

Comment: Sorry, i was a little busy these days.
Yes it can be done by Googles ml kit and ar plugin but the main question here is how to implement these plugins and import the AR model and apply it on the video while recording it. I cant even extract frames from the video while recording in flutter. If anyone has previously worked with this then it would be a really good help.

Comment: Again, details are needed for answering most technical questions. 1. What have you tried (including the commands issued / tools used) 2. What was the expected results 3. What was / is the actual results (including error messages, links to logs etc) 4. What have you done in terms of troubleshooting before deciding to ask this question

Answer (score 4):

#### Not The Easiest Question To Answer, But...

I'll give it a go, let's see how things turn out.
First of all, you should fill in some more details about the statements given in the question, especially what you're trying to say here:

> *I know there are packages like AR core and flutter_camera_ml_vision but these are not helping me.*

**How did you approach the problem and what makes you say that it didn't help you?**

#### In the Beginning...

First of all, let's get some needed basics out of the way to better understand your current situation and level in the prerequisite areas of knowledge:

- Do you have any experience using Computer Vision & Machine Learning frameworks in other languages / in other apps?
- Do you have the required math skills needed to use this technology?
- As you're using Flutter, my guess is that cross-platform compatibility is high priority, have you done much Flutter programming before and what devices are your main targets?

**So, What is required for creating a Snapchat-like filter for use in live video recording?**

Well, quite a lot of work happens behind the scenes when you apply a filter to live video using any app that implements this in a decent way.

**Snapchat** uses in-house software that they've built up over years, using technology acquired from multiple multi-million dollar company acquisitions, often established companies that specialized in Computer Vision and AR technology, in addition to their own efforts, and has steadily grown to be quite impressive through the last 5-6 years in particular.

This isn't something you can throw together by yourself as an "all night'er" and expect good results. But there are tools available for easing the general learning curve, but these tools also require a firm understanding of the underlying concepts and technologies being used, and quite a lot of math.

#### The Technical Detour

OK, I know I may have went a bit overboard here, but this is fundamental building blocks, not so many are aware of the actual amount of computation needed for seemingly "basic" functionality, so please, TLDR; or not, this is fundamental stuff.

To create a good filter for live capture using a camera on something like an iPhone or Android device, you could, and most probably would, use AR as you mentioned you wanted to use in the end, but realize that this is a sub-set of the broad field of Computer Vision (CV) that uses various algorithms from Artificial Intelligence (AI) and Machine Learning (ML) for the main tasks of:

- Facial Recognition
  Given frames of video content from the live camera, define the area containing a human face (some also works with animals, but let's keep it as simple as possible) and output a rectangle suitable for use as a starting point in (x, y, for width & height).

  The analysis phase alone will require a rather complex combination of algorithms / techniques from different parts of the AI universe, and this being video, not a single static image file, this must be continuously updated as the person / camera moves, so it must be done in close to real-time, in the millisecond range.

  I believe different implementations combining [HOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) (Histogram of Oriented Gradients) from Computer Vision and [SVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (Support Vector Machines / Networks) from Machine Learning are still pretty common.
- Detection of Facial Landmarks
  This is what will define how well a certain effect / filter will adapt to different types of facial features and detect accessories like glasses, hats etc. Also called "facial keypoint detection", "facial feature detection" and other variants in different literature on the subject.
- Head Pose Estimation
  Once you know a few landmark points, you can also estimate the pose of the head.
  This is an important part of effects like "face swap" to correctly re-align one face with another in an acceptable manner. A toolkit like [OpenFace](https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace) (Uses Python, OpenCV, OpenBLAS, Dlib ++) contains a lot of useful functionality, capable of facial landmark detection, head pose estimation, facial action unit recognition, and eye-gaze estimation, delivering pretty decent results.
- The Compositing of Effects into the Video Frames
  After the work with the above is done, the rest involves applying the target filter, dog ears, rabbit teeth, whatever to the video frames, using compositing techniques.
  As this answer is starting to look more like an article, I'll leave it to you to go figure out if you want to know more of the details in this part of the process.

#### Hey, Dude. I asked for AR in Flutter, remember?

Yep.
I know, I can get a bit carried away.
Well, my point is that it takes a lot more than one would usually imagine creating something like you ask for.

BUT.
My best advice if Flutter is your tool of choice would be to learn how to use the Cloud-Based ML services from Google's Firebase suite of tools, [Firebase Machine Learning](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml) and Google's [MLKit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit).

Add to this some AR-specific plugins, like the [ARCore Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_plugin), and I'm sure you'll be able to get the pieces together if you have the right background and attitude, plus a good amount of aptitude for learning.

Hope this wasn't digressing too far from your core question, but there are no shortcuts that I know of that cut more corners than what I've already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could absolutely use the [flutter_camera_ml_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_camera_ml_vision) plugin and it's face recognition which will give you positions for landmarks of a face, such as, nose, eyes etc. Then simply stack the CameraPreview with a CustomPaint(foregroundPainter: widget in which you draw your filters using the different landmarks as coordinates for i.e. glasses, beards or whatever you want at the correct position of the face in the camera preview.

Google ML Kit also has face recognition that produces landmarks and you could write your own flutter plugin for that.

You can capture frames from the live camera preview and reformat them and then it as a byte buffer to ML kit or ML vision. I am currently writing a flutter plugin for ML kit pose detection with live capture so if you have any specific question about that let me know.

You will then have to merge the two surfaces and save to file in appropriate format. This is unknown territory for me so I can not provide any details about this part.

Comment: >*Two specific answers* - I mentioned both as well. But I liked your part about horses.